# Ignore converting text to a list

Tags: kirby

I can't get following content to be generated without building the HTML list structure around.

```
Merke Dir auch gleich den nächsten Termin:
12. November 2015
```

Kirbytext will then generate this:

```
<p>Merke Dir auch gleich den nächsten Termin:</p>
<ol>
  <li>November 2015</li>
</ol>
```

But i need just the Content in normal p-tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the dot with the Markdown escaper \ (backslash)

Instead of writing:

```
12. November 2015
```

Write:

```
12\. November 2015
```

This should solve your issue.